# Classifying abelian numbers

Tags: group-theory, induction, group-homomorphism, sylow-theory, semidirect-product

I am stuck on this problem from Dummit and Foote (exercise 5.5.24).

> Let $n$ be an integer $> 1$. Prove the following classification: every group of order $n$ is abelian if and only if $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}...p_r^{\alpha_r}$, where $p_1,...,p_r$ are distinct primes, $\alpha_i=1$ or $2$ for all $i\in\{1,...,r\}$ and $p_i$ does not divide $p_j^{\alpha_j}-1$ for all $I$ and $j$. [See Exercise 56 in section 4.5]

Now exercise 56 (and the ones preceding it) were a series of exercises classifying all "cyclic numbers" ie. numbers $n$ such that if $G$ is a group of order $n$, then $G$ is necessarily cyclic. The subsequent result was very similar to this, and exercise 56 yielded the additional result that every finite group in which all proper subgroups are abelian is solvable (and not simple).

Considering how these exercises worked I assume I need to work with an inductive argument, though I am not sure how to execute it. I also imagine I might need to construct a normal subgroup $H$ and its complement $K$ (Sylow theorems?) to work with their semi-direct product $H\rtimes_{\varphi} K$ and show that the only possible homomorphism $\varphi: K\to \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ defining this product is trivial. I haven't succeeded in implementing any of these ideas thus far. Any hint in the right direction would be of great help.

Comment: Can you at least show that if any $\alpha$ is $3$ or more, or if there is an $i$ and $j$ such that $p_i|p_j^{\alpha}-1$, then there is a group with that many elements that is not abelian? That  would give you the "only if" clause.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes by constructing the group by a few direct products. This is the way it was done for the cyclic case as well.

Comment: In order to prove 'only if', you need to know:

1) that the group of matrices
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \mathbb{Z}_p & \mathbb{Z}_p\\
0 & 1 & \mathbb{Z}_p\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is non-Abelian for any prime number p;

2) the multiplicative group of a field of order $p^\alpha$ is a
cyclic group of order $p^\alpha-1$ and multiplication by a nonzero
element of this field is an automorphism of the additive group of
this field;

3) and also to be able to construct a semidirect product of
groups.

I don't know if it can be simpler.

Comment: @kabenyuk: "Need to know" is too much; certainly that information will let you construct nonabelian groups of the appropriate order, but it is hardly the only possible way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks @Arturo Magidin. Yes, apparently I should have said useful to know.

Comment: The pointer is to a problem that states that a group with all proper subgroups abelian is solvable. That suggests using induction via the method of least counterexample: assume the result is false, and let $G$ be a group of minimal order among those that are counterexamples  to the statement. Then all proper subgroups are abelian, and hence $G$ is solvable. Thus, $[G,G]$ is proper (and hence abelian). Try to go from there.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I must be misunderstanding: if $G$ is a counterexample to the statement then $G$ is abelian for an $n$ not accounted for by the exercise. But then $[G,G]=1$ is not proper?

Comment: @LittleNarwhal: No: the statement doesn't say that group is abelian if and only if it has that order. The statement says that every group of that order is abelian if and only if certain conditions on the order are met. A counterexample would be a group $G$ whose order statisfies all of those conditions, but is *not* abelian. The fact that $G$ is not abelian tells you $[G,G]$ is not the trivial subgroup. (BTW: the trivial subgroup is a proper subgroup of any group that is not trivial) The fact that $G$ must be solvable implies that $[G,G]\neq G$.

Comment: Note that if the order of $G$ satisfies all the given conditions, then so does the order of any subgroup of $G$. That's why if $G$ is a minimal counterexample, then all proper subgroups of $G$ are abelian, and hence by Problem 56 of section 4.5, $G$ itself is solvable.

Comment: Right of course, ill try to work from there tomorrow morning. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so in comments you say that you already know the "only if" clause. Let's discuss the "if" clause.

Assume the result holds for any group of order strictly smaller than $|G|$ satisfying the given conditions. In particular, since every subgroup and quotient of $G$ has order satisfying the given conditions, any proper subgroup of $G$ and any proper quotient of $G$ is abelian.

Note that the result follows easily if $r=1$. If $r=2$, then the Sylow $p_i$-subgroups are normal (the number of them must divide $p_j^{\alpha}$ for the other $j$, and be congruent to $1$ modulo $p_i$, which can only happen if the number is $1$ since $p_i$ doe snot divide $p_j^{\alpha}-1$). And so $G$ is the direct product of two abelian groups, hence abelian. So we may assume that $r\geq 3$.

By the referenced problem 56 of section 4.5, it follows that $G$ is solvable, since every proper subgroup of $G$ is abelian.
Consider $[G,G]$, which is a proper subgroup of $G$ (and hence abelian).

I claim first that $[G,G]$ is a $p$-group. Indeed, if this is not the case then we can write $[G,G]=A\times B$, with $A$ and $B$ nontrivial and of relatively prime orders. But then $A$ and $B$ are characteristic in $[G,G]$, and hence normal in $G$. Then $G/A$ is abelian (since it is a proper quotient of $G$), contradicting the fact that $[G,G]$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ such that the quotient is abelian. Thus, $[G,G]$ is a $p$-group. Let $P$ be a Sylow subgroup of $G$ that contains $[G,G]$; say it is the $p_i$-subgroup. Note that because it contains $[G,G]$, it is normal.

If $p_j\neq p_i$, and $P_j$ is a Sylow $p_j$-subgroup of $G$, then $[G,G]P_j$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $G$ (subgroup because $[G,G]$ is normal, normal because any subgroup containing $[G,G]$ is normal, abelian because it is a proper subgroup of $G$ since $r\geq 3$). Since $P_j$ is characteristic in $[G,G]P_j$, because $\gcd(|[G,G]|,|P_j|)=1$, it is normal in $G$. But that means that the Sylow $p_j$-subgroup of $G$ is normal for any $p_j\neq p_i$, and we already knew the Sylow $p_i$-subgroup is normal. Thus,
$G=P_1\times\cdots\times P_r$, where $P_i$ is the Sylow $p_i$-subgroup of $G$. Since each $P_i$ is of order $p_i$ or $p_i^2$, it is abelian. Hence $G$ is abelian, as claimed.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Every integer has a prime factorization so this is not a condition. Then the forward implication is: if every group of order $n$ is abelian, then both conditions, $\alpha_{i}=1$ or $2$ for all $i\in\left\{1,\ldots ,r\right\}$, and $p_{i}$ does not divide $p_{j}^{\alpha_{j}}-1$ for all $i$ and $j$, must hold. For the contrapositive, one or the other or both of the latter conditions must fail. In case $\alpha_{k}>2$ it is possible to constuct a non-abelian subgroup of order $p_{k}^{3}$ via a semidirect product (Example~5.5(7)). Similarly, if $p_{i}$ does divide $p_{j}^{\alpha_{j}}-1$ for some $i$ and $j$, it is possible to construct a non-abelian subgroup via a semidirect product. Thus the contrapositive and so the forward implication.

The reverse implication is: if $\alpha_{i}=1$ or $2$ for all $i\in\left\{1,\ldots ,r\right\}$, and $p_{i}$ does not divide $p_{j}^{\alpha_{j}}-1$ for all $i$ and $j$, then every group of order $n$ is abelian. Induct on the number of distinct primes in the factorization of $n$ and observe that the hypothesis $p_{i}$ does not divide $p_{j}^{\alpha_{j}}-1$ for all $i$ and $j$ implies groups with orders $p_{i}$, $p_{i}^{2}$, $p_{i}p_{j}$, $p_{i}^{2}p_{j}$, and $p_{i}^{2}p_{j}^{2}$ are abelian. The latter list could serve as a base case for the induction; however, the proof for $3$ distinct prime factors is canonical and is given explicitly.

There are $2^{r}=\sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{r}{k}$ ways of distributing the exponent $2$ over $r$ distinct primes so there are $r+1$ ($0\leq k\leq r$) possible types of group order for any particular choice of $r$. In particular, for $r=3$ there are the $4$ possibilities
\begin{align*}
    &p_{1}p_{2}p_{3}
    \qquad p_{1}^{2}p_{2}p_{3}
    \qquad p_{1}^{2}p_{2}^{2}p_{3}
    \qquad p_{1}^{2}p_{2}^{2}p_{3}^{2}
\end{align*}

A finite induction over $k$ will determine that each of these $4$ types must be abelian. Start with the type $\left|G\right|=p_{1}p_{2}p_{3}$ corresponding to $k=0$ and observe that any proper non-trivial subgroups have order types $p_{i}$ or $p_{i}p_{j}$ so all proper subgroups are abelian. Exercise~4.5.56 provides a proper normal subgroup $N$, abelian by the induction hypothesis, so $G/N$ is abelian ($G$ is solvable). Let the corresponding Sylow subgroups of $G$ be $P_{1}$, $P_{2}$, and $P_{3}$. There is $P_{i}$ so $P_{i}N$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. Then $P_{i}N$ is abelian so $P_{i}$ is normal; hence, characteristic in $P_{i}N$ (Corollary~4.5.20). That is, $P_{i}$ is normal in $G$ so $P_{i}P_{j}$ is abelian in $G$ so $P_{i}$ is normal in $G$ for all $i$. It is an immediate consequence of Theorem~5.4.9 that $G\cong P_{1}\times P_{2}\times P_{3}$, a direct product of abelian groups, so $G$ is abelian.

The second type $\left|G\right|=p_{1}^{2}p_{2}p_{3}$ corresponds to $k=1$ and observe that any proper non-trivial subgroups have order types $p_{i}$, $p_{i}^{2}$, $p_{i}p_{j}$, $p_{i}^{2}p_{j}$, and $p_{i}p_{j}p_{k}$ so all proper subgroups are abelian. It is the possibility for a subgroup of type $p_{i}p_{j}p_{k}$ that requires a finite induction over $k$. Exercise~4.5.56 provides a proper normal subgroup $N$, abelian by the induction hypothesis, so $G/N$ is abelian ($G$ is solvable). Let the corresponding Sylow subgroups of $G$ be $P_{1}$, $P_{2}$, and $P_{3}$. There is $P_{i}$ so $P_{i}N$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. Then $P_{i}N$ is abelian so $P_{i}$ is normal; hence, characteristic in $P_{i}N$ (Corollary~4.5.20). That is, $P_{i}$ is normal in $G$ so $P_{i}P_{j}$ is abelian in $G$ so $P_{i}$ is normal in $G$ for all $i$. It is an immediate consequence of Theorem~5.4.9 that $G\cong P_{1}\times P_{2}\times P_{3}$, a direct product of abelian groups, so $G$ is abelian. The rest of the finite induction proceeds similarly. The induction over $r$ is then obvious. Thus the result.